# Can i make dram using bjt transistors?

Tags: bjt, dram

Is it possible to make dram using bjt's or is it only possible with mosfet's? If not why not? Is there an advantage in using mosfets instead of something like a bjt ?

Comment: where I live, we make drams from barley.

Comment: @BrianDrummond We enjoy a wee dram from time to time on this side of the pond too :-).

Comment: then why do everyone use mosfets?

Comment: Please provide other specs like speed and voltage.

Comment: https://shelfkey.com/DataSheets/77324893.pdf this is the link to the datasheet

Comment: Why use solid rubber tyres when you get a much smoother ride with inflatable tyres?

Comment: The comments you are getting are very specific and a bit of tweeking of your nose.  They wouldn't use MOSFETs if there wasn't an advantage over bjt.  You need to add more details and you'll get better quality comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic RAM as some RAM which stores bits in a capacitor and needs to be periodically refreshed, you could make one with a bipolar transistor or even a valve/vacuum tube or a relay.
There were many concepts in early days of computings of memories with only temporary storage.

Dynamic RAM as the concept of using a very clever arrangement of a capacitor made of silicon controlled by a single transistor using MOSFET technology processes, then you cannot replicate it without having a semiconductor fab.

Comment: so is it possible to use a bjt and a capacitor to store one bit?

Comment: There was an early memory that used a rotating drum with capacitors connected to contacts, that acted more or less as an electromechanical dynamic ram.

Comment: See the statement above "you could make one with a bipolar transistor".  So -- yes.

Comment: so why does everyone use a mosfet instead?

Comment: You'd need an impractically large capacitor or refresh rate to use a BJT in an IC DRAM though you could probably figure out a way to create a bit on a breadboard. That said, wikipedia implies that early IC DRAM's *were* in a bipolar technology. 
 The mention of using a "relay" in this answer makes it absurd... yes, one can use a relay as a memory device, but _not_ realistically in a DRAM.

Comment: Not only MOSFETs have higher input impedance than BJT which makes them far better for sensing the capacitor, but the fabrication process of planar MOSFETs integrated circuits naturally allows to create the capacitors needed for DRAM, without additional steps (actually it's a bit more complex)

Comment: Yes - MOSFETs inherently have a gate capacitance, and a low leakage compared to the constant current that would flow through the base of a BJT. Really in digital design the question is "why do you want a BJT when everything else is a MOSFET?"

Comment: @ChrisStratton Absurd is such a strong word :-). One can imagine eg reed relays with capacitors able to hold them up for many ms and refreshed suitably frequently. Horrendous? Oh yes. Absurd? Moot. Considering wire coil pulse storage memories (I have a calculator that uses one), mercury tank memories, rotating drum whole memories (registers and all) not to mention "modern" rotating rust HDD storage, then maybe not quite absurd :-)